# Exception while accessing KafkaOffset from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

I have a Spark consumer which streams from Kafka.
I am trying to manage offsets for exactly-once semantics.

However, while accessing the offset it throws the following exception:

> "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.HasOffsetRanges"

The part of the code that does this is as below :

```
var offsetRanges = Array[OffsetRange]()
dataStream
  .transform { 
    rdd =>
      offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
      rdd
   }
   .foreachRDD(rdd => { })
```

Here dataStream is a direct stream(DStream[String]) created using KafkaUtils API something like :

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Set(source_schema+"_"+t)).map(_._2)
```

If somebody can help me understand what I am doing wrong here.
transform is the first method in the chain of methods performed on datastream as mentioned in the official documentation as well

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
.map(._2)
```

Which creates a `MapPartitionedDStream` instead of the `DirectKafkaInputDStream` created by `KafkaUtils.createKafkaStream`.

You need to `map` after `transform`:

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Set(source_schema+""+t))

kafkaStream
  .transform { 
    rdd => 
      offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
      rdd
  }
  .map(_._2)
  .foreachRDD(rdd => // stuff)
```

Comment: also, while trying to create direct stream using offsets, I am encountering an error. <br/>
val fromOffsets : (TopicAndPartition, Long)= TopicAndPartition(metrics_rs.getString(1), metrics_rs.getInt(2)) -> metrics_rs.getLong(3) <br/>
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder,(String, String)](ssc,kafkaParams,fromOffsets,messageHandler) <br/>

where,
val messageHandler =
      (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => mmd.message.length
and metrics_rs is the result set from which I am fetching the offsets map. It says too many type arguments error

Comment: How to read offsetRanges in my below code. I am using repartition.  val numPartitionsOfInputTopic = 2
      val streams = (1 to numPartitionsOfInputTopic) map {
        _ => KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams) ).map(_.value())
      }

      val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams)
      val sparkProcessingParallelism = 1
      unifiedStream.repartition(sparkProcessingParallelism)
 more details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344461/spark-kafka-streaming-commitasync-error