# Spark Kafka Streaming CommitAsync Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, scala-streams

I am new to Scala and RDD concept. Reading message from kafka using Kafka stream api in Spark and trying to commit after business work. but I am getting error.

Note: Using repartition for Parallel work

How to read offset from stream APi and commit it to Kafka ?

> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"  val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"  val
>   connectorVersion = "2.0.7"  val kafka_stream_version = "1.6.3"

**Code**

```
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(2))
    ssc.checkpoint("C:/Gnana/cp")

    val kafkaStream = {

      val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
        "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
        "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "group.id" -> "ignite3",

        "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
        "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
      )

      val topics = Array("test")
      val numPartitionsOfInputTopic = 2
      val streams = (1 to numPartitionsOfInputTopic) map {
        _ => KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams) ).map(_.value())
      }

      val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams)
      val sparkProcessingParallelism = 1
      unifiedStream.repartition(sparkProcessingParallelism)
    }
//Finding offsetRanges
kafkaStream
  .transform {
    rdd =>
      offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
      rdd
  }
//do business operation and persist offset to kafka
kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd=> {
  println("offsetRanges:"+offsetRanges)
  rdd.foreach(conRec=> {
    println(conRec)
    kafkaStream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
  })
})

    println(" Spark parallel reader is ready !!!")

   ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
```

**Error**

java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream is being serialized  possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because  the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure.  Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this.  This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks  with unnecessary objects.
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(DStream.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStream.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStream.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.writeObject(DStream.scala:512)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)

Comment: @yuval , I am using repartition concept. it is not same as that question. it is bit different. please help me on this

Comment: Gnana, do you really need to write parallel reader program? Does the parameter (--num-executors) not take care of parallelism with multiple topic partitions?

Comment: @kiranM I would like to do with parallel . if it is not possible. give me sample code where it will read message after business logic write to Kafka

Comment: I mean to say you don't need to manually write code for parallelism, DirectStream (createDirectStream) will take care of automatically based on "--num-executors" parameter.

Comment: @kiranM I need to read message from one topic which has multiple partition and process the data and commit in Kafka. I don't want repartition.

Comment: Yes, coming to your CommitAsync error, I have a working code you can try. Where can I paste the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167129/discussion-between-kiranm-and-gnana).

Answer (score 0):

Don't repartition before calculating offset ranges. If you do so then will encounter this issue. To test you simply remove repartition and then try running this application.